# Is there a way to tell if a user came from another page on my site

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I have a loading screen that is basically a modal over my index page. I only want it show up when a user comes to my site initially. The screen isn’t really important for functionality, but when things load on the index page, images and other things flicker around a bit depending on a few variables I can set using url params. I want to have a nice, clean user experience for the first load at least. 
But after the first load, the loading screen gets annoying as it covers the homepage each time it is loading.

I have used document.referrer for the time being, so at least if the home menu button is clicked, I can detect that. But the issue I am facing is if a user uses the back button.

I thought about using local storage, but the issue with this would be that if a user is on my page, goes to another website and then comes back, I would like to start with the loading page again. If I set a session cookie that wouldn’t happen.

I’m thinking the best solution is to set a cookie that lasts for about 30seconds to a minute for each page visited. I can write the code to do that, and am not asking for help with that, I’m just wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: look at the referer?

Comment: as mentioned, I am using document.referrer for the time being, but that doesn't work with the back button

Comment: Why don't you just hide everything until it is loaded and to deal with the flickering?

Comment: not sure how a cookie would help with 30 seconds. Guess you are setting it onunload of the page?

Comment: the unload cookie would work perfectly actually. as for hiding, I could do that as well, but the load time is about 2.5 seconds, and I feel like it may cause a little confusion if the screen is just blank for that long. I think I will use a combination of both. use the loading screen on initial load, and then render just the header and hide the body until it is loaded in other instances

Comment: So add a message on the page when it is loading.